# TFS 2010 - New work item - auto select Assigned To with your Id

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is there a way to select the logged-on user for the Assigned-To field when a workitem is created.

Right now, when we create a bug, the assigned-To field is blank.  The user then has to select the person (most of the time, him/herself) out of the available list..

I tried this out with TFS2005 and it was working so I'm curious as to what has to be changed.

Comment: What did you do in TFS2005 to make it work that way?

Comment: I can't remember for the life of me.  I checked a default workitem and didn't see any change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure how to do it through GUI as it has been while, but in the `xml`, you can set it like this:

```
  <TRANSITIONS>
    <TRANSITION from="" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Identified" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <DEFAULT from="currentuser" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    .....
  </TRANSITIONS>
```

Comment: I ended up putting the field in the transition from="" to="Active" instead but the result was the samwe.  Thanks, that jogged my memory of what I had done 5 years ago with TFS2005

Comment: Yeah, you can put it in any transition. I just mentioned it for the sake of completeness. Here's a tip: Always look at the template `xml` to bring back memories (that's how I found it)!